# How to arrange controls horizontally with even spacing in WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm, controls, docking

I am looking for a flexible way to arrange rectangular controls inside a grid with an even spacing. The controls are added/removed dynamically. Eventually I wish to let user select one of the layouts below:

[image]

I am thinking of using UniformGrid and let the rest be handled by grid's properties:

```
<UniformGrid>
    <Button Content="Button 1"/>
    <Button Content="Button 2"/>
    <Button Content="Button 3"/>
    <Button Content="Button 4"/>
    <Button Content="Button 5"/>
</UniformGrid>
```

However, my concern is my future ability to customize the layout as in option 3 (see image above). I am looking for suggestions of how to make this as flexible as possible considering I am following MVVM in my design.

Comment: If you know the dimensions of the Buttons, and the dimensions of whatever container you're going to put them in, a WrapPanel and some margin settings might do the job.

Comment: Personally I'd use an `ItemsControl` with the `ItemsPanelTemplate` set to either a `UniformGrid`, `WrapPanel`, or `Grid` depending on your requirements. That's the control that is meant to display a collection of objects in a uniform way, and it can easily be styled/templated to display items in any way you want.

Comment: @Rachel You've mentioned WrapPanel and I looked into it more closely, so now am surprised I haven't payed too much attention to it. Add this to the answers and I'll mark it, works for me.

Comment: @eYe Sure, answer posted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `WrapPanel` can be used to display any number of items, and will automatically wrap to another row if the items exceed the allowed width.

```
<WrapPanel>
    <Button Content="Button 1"/>
    <Button Content="Button 2"/>
    <Button Content="Button 3"/>
    <Button Content="Button 4"/>
    <Button Content="Button 5"/>
</WrapPanel>
```

Alternatively if you're looking for something more structured where you can define a dynamic layout for controls, I'd suggest an `ItemsControl` with the `ItemsPanelTemplate` set to either a `UniformGrid`, `WrapPanel`, or `Grid` depending on your requirements. [James Lucas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29827254/302677) provides a good example for that.

Answer (score 4):

Use a UniformGrid and bind the count for Columns and Rows. Use it as the panel for an items control and you can get MVVM separation.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource={Binding X}>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
       <ItemsPanelTemplate>
          <UniformGrid Rows={Binding...} />
     </ItemsPanelTemplate>    
   </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```